# ¿Cómo mostrar barra lateral de colores usando Floris de NREL?

Tags: python, plot

Estoy haciendo uso de la librería Floris de NREL para Python, con el objetivo de simular las estelas de un aerogenerador (la librería y su código puede consultarse en https://github.com/NREL/floris). Estoy haciendo uso del ejemplo 1 (puede consultarse en https://github.com/NREL/floris/blob/main/examples/_getting_started/example_00_open_and_vis_floris.py) Estoy graficando el resultado para una única turbina. El plot resultante es el siguiente:

[image: Estela para una sola turbina]

Sin embargo, me gustaría añadir la barra lateral de leyenda, tal y como aparece en la siguiente figura:

[image: Plot with side bar]

El principal problema es que al tratarse de un paquete, el código trabaja con muchas funciones definidas que no puedo detallar aquí, por eso indico las direcciones de las librerías. El código del ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import floris.tools as wfct
file_dir = '...\example_input.json' #directorio
fi = wfct.floris_interface.FlorisInterface(file_dir)
# Calcular estela
fi.calculate_wake()
# Plano horizontal
hor_plane = fi.get_hor_plane()
# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
wfct.visualization.visualize_cut_plane(hor_plane, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

El archivo example_input.json se puede encontrar en: https://github.com/NREL/floris/blob/main/examples/example_input.json

Comment: Si aportas con el código que ya tienes escrito, podríamos empezar a trabajar en una respuesta.

Comment: Buenas, Josue, aparte de lo que indica Candid Moe, deberías traducir tu pregunta al español o será cerrada.

Comment: Traducida al español y código añadido!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = wfct.visualization.visualize_cut_plane(hor_plane,ax=ax)
cax = fig.add_axes([ax.get_position().x1+0.01,ax.get_position().y0,0.02,ax.get_position().height])
ax.set_title("Baseline flow for U = 8 m/s, Wind Direction = 270$^\\circ$")
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, label='m/s')
```

Resultado:

[image: Estela de aerogeneradores con barra lateral]

Comment: por favor explica un poco lo que haces, así se entenderá mejor como es que se solucionó y ayudarás a los demás

Comment: Para entender lo que hago es necesario consultar la librería Floris en los enlaces que proporciono. Es demasiado grande como para indicarlo todo aquí. Básicamente, lo que estoy haciendo es calcular las estelas que se pueden observar en un parque eólico de acuerdo con unos parámetros de entrada. Los ejes X e Y del gráfico indican cómo se distribuyen los aerogeneradores en el mapa/terreno, mientras que los colores informan sobre el efecto en la velocidad del viento. El problema era que no conseguía pintar la leyenda (la barra de color del lateral derecho) de la gráfica, pero ya está resuelto.

Comment: No digo que expliques todo solo haz un pequeño resumen de las funciones y métodos utilizas y por que lo utilizas, recomiendo que lees [¿Cómo elaboro una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)